# How can I make a tensorflow model take lists as input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm new with tensorflow, and I'm making an AI that does multiplication,

and I need to make it so that my model can take lists as input.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

multiplication_q = np.array([[10,10],[1,1],[2,2],[0,0],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[1,0],[11,10],[27,0],[30,2],[4,3],[17,22],[20,0],[8,13],[21,4],[19,24],[11,19],[8,2],[4,5],[11,11],[1,15],[2,12],[15,3],[18,0],[49,7],[5,7],[12,4]], dtype=object)
multiplication_a = np.array([100,1,4,0,9,16,25,36,49,64,96,0,110,0,60,12,374,0,104,84,456,209,16,20,121,15,24,45,0,343,35,48], dtype=float)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=[1]),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))

history = model.fit(multiplication_q, multiplication_a, epochs=750, verbose=False)

print(model.predict([4, 5]))
```

and here is the error message:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:976 __call__
        self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [32, 2]
```

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you consulted the relevant documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your issue you should do 3 things:

1- Change the `dtype` in the `multiplication_q` from `object` to `int` like this:

```
multiplication_q = np.array([[10,10],[1,1],[2,2],[0,0],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[1,0],[11,10],[27,0],[30,2],[4,3],[17,22],[20,0],[8,13],[21,4],[19,24],[11,19],[8,2],[4,5],[11,11],[1,15],[2,12],[15,3],[18,0],[49,7],[5,7],[12,4]], dtype=int)
```

2- And in the first Dense layer of your model use `input_shape=(2,)` instead of `input_shape=[1]`, like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=(2,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
```

3- And for the predict function you should pass a `list` of `list` and not a `list`, cause you did a training with `list` of `list`

```
model.predict([[4, 5]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your input in the first dense layer to `multiplication_q.shape`, you set your input shape to be `1` while your input is shaped `32, 2`

EDIT: The code below resolved your issue although you will have to play around with stuff because it is not very accurate.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

multiplication_q = np.asarray([[10,10],[1,1],[2,2],[0,0],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[1,0],[11,10],[27,0],[30,2],[4,3],[17,22],[20,0],[8,13],[21,4],[19,24],[11,19],[8,2],[4,5],[11,11],[1,15],[2,12],[15,3],[18,0],[49,7],[5,7],[12,4]])
multiplication_a = np.asarray([100,1,4,0,9,16,25,36,49,64,96,0,110,0,60,12,374,0,104,84,456,209,16,20,121,15,24,45,0,343,35,48])


multiplication_q = multiplication_q/np.amax(multiplication_q)
multiplication_a = multiplication_a/np.amax(multiplication_a)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(2, )))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))

history = model.fit(multiplication_q, multiplication_a, epochs=750)

print(model.predict(np.asarray([[4, 5]])/np.amax(multiplication_q)*np.amax(multiplication_a)))
```

Comment: It worked with model.fit(), but now there's an error with model.predict().